# Make Django Form Validation For Reservation

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i make a reservation system, which has form validation,

This should check whether the the bus on that date is already booked or not,

but, unfortunately there still error on this code..

so here my code :

```
forms.py

class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = '__all__'
    
    tempReDate = date(1,1,1) # temp local variable
    
    def clean_start(self):
        start = self.cleaned_data['start']

        #  cheacking if date for this bus is free
        res_all = Booking.objects.all()
        for item in res_all:
            if start  >= item.start and start <= item.end  and item.resourceId == self.instance.resourceId:
                raise forms.ValidationError("This date already reserved by same bus, choose other date or other bus")
        #set variable to send for next funtion: clean_EndDate
        self.tempReDate = start
        return start

    def clean_end(self):
        #check if EndDate is empty
        if not self.data['end']:
            #set numbers days of reservation 1 if no end date
            self.instance.numOfDays =  1
            return None

        # if start date is empty
        if self.tempReDate == date(1,1,1):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Must Choose start date")

        # if start date is not empty
        else:
            start = self.tempReDate
            end = self.cleaned_data['end']

            # cheackig start date is not lower than end date
            if end < start:
                raise forms.ValidationError("start date cannot be later than end date")

            # cheackig if reservation is no longer than 14 days
            if end > start+ timedelta(days=14):
                raise forms.ValidationError("You can make a reservation for max 14 days")

            #  cheacking if reservation  for this bus is free
            res_all = Booking.objects.all().filter(resourceId=self.instance.resourceId)
            for item in res_all:

                #jesli w przedziale nowego zamowienia jest poczatek albo koniec innego to zajęte
                if start <= item.start and item.start <= end or start <= item.end and item.end <= end:
                    raise forms.ValidationError("This date already reserved by same bus, choose other date or other bus")

        # calculateing number  days of reservation and save it
        var = end - start
        self.instance.numOfDays = var.days + 1
        return start
```

And this code on views.py

```
views.py

def create_book(request):
    booking_forms = BookingForm()
    customer_forms = CustomerForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        booking_forms = BookingForm(request.POST)
        customer_forms = CustomerForm(request.POST)
        if customer_forms.is_valid() and booking_forms.is_valid():
            nama_pelanggan = customer_forms.cleaned_data['nama_pelanggan']
            no_hp = customer_forms.cleaned_data['no_hp']

            # nmpl = request.POST['nama_pelanggan']
            # nm_pl = {"nama_pelanggan": nmpl}

            customer, _ = Customer.objects.get_or_create(no_hp=customer_forms.cleaned_data['no_hp'],
            defaults={
                'nama_pelanggan': customer_forms.cleaned_data['nama_pelanggan'],
                'alamat_pelanggan': '',
                'tipe': ''
            },)

            idbooking = booking_forms.cleaned_data['idbooking']
            resourceId = booking_forms.cleaned_data['resourceId']
            start = booking_forms.cleaned_data['start']
            end = booking_forms.cleaned_data['end']
            harga_jual = booking_forms.cleaned_data['harga_jual']
            uang_jalan = booking_forms.cleaned_data['uang_jalan']
            parkir_bensin = booking_forms.cleaned_data['parkir_bensin']
            note = booking_forms.cleaned_data['note']
            
            Booking.objects.create(
                idbooking=idbooking,
                resourceId=resourceId,
                start=start,
                end=end,
                harga_jual=harga_jual,
                uang_jalan=uang_jalan,
                parkir_bensin=parkir_bensin,
                note=note,
                title=resourceId,
                nm_pelanggan=nama_pelanggan,
                backgroundColor='blue'
            ),
            return redirect('booking-list')

        else:
            print(booking_forms.errors)
            print(customer_forms.errors)
        
    context = {
        'cform': customer_forms,
        'form': booking_forms,
    }

    return render(request, 'booking/create_book.html', context)
```

What error ?

The problem im facing now, when i make reservation use same bus on same date, the validation error message not showing, and program continue make booking which is make double booking and will make conflict
.
what is problem with this form validation ?
.
thanks

Comment: It might help to show the error you are getting. EDIT: Nevermind, I see you say you don't get an error. I'd start with the booking_forms and customer_forms both coming from the request post - not sure how that would be working. I don't see how both can ever be valid at the same time (but I learn new things everyday)

Comment: @AMG
yeah u can try its working, use multiple form on one submit..
so i think its not the issue.. now im handling this error using if on models validation not on forms..